# Unity Push notification

Tags: ios, unity-game-engine, push-notification

I'm having this problem for weeks now and I haven't seen any solution on the internet. I hope someone can point me to the right direction. How do I open an app programmatically or perform something after tapping a received push notification from the notification bar?

Comment: Do you want to open some viewControllers programatically on clicking push notifications that you receive?

Comment: I want to do something like opening a specific scene after tapping a notification..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should make yourself familiar with the Unity [NotificationServices](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/NotificationServices.html).

It is the proper place to schedule `LocalNotifications`, and then handle both them and `RemoteNotifications` (Push).

On you application start (or on coming back from being paused, see [OnApplicationPause](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnApplicationPause.html)), you should check for the `localNotificationCount` or `remoteNotificationCount`, and if there are any, then you should handle them.

You don't need any external plugin to do this, just use the built-in unity features.